# Can I receive android push notifications via AWS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

Essentially, what I would like to do is provision an AWS resource to mimic a user's phone to track push notifications from various applications. For example, the Netflix app will occasionally receive push notifications to inform users about new content being released. Is there any way I could set up a service via AWS (maybe an EC2 instance) to receive these notifications from multiple applications (say I want to receive push notifications from Hulu and Netflix, e.g.) and log them without the need to actually have these applications installed on a physical device. Is this possible? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be running Android or iOS, to receive push notifications. So, you're looking at physical mobile devices, or emulated devices.

[AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/) is one option. It is more intended for short, ephemeral use, though. Please consider the [Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/) and [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faqs/) while considering this solution. If you'll use a device full-time, consider a [private device](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/working-with-private-devices.html).

Another option is to run an Android or iOS emulator on a physical machine. Android notifications *do* arrive on the emulator, although with *very poor reliability*, in my experience. You could run on Android emulator on an [EC2 host](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), or in an [EC2 Container](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

---

The most interesting aspect of your project is how to read/process the incoming notification data, once you have it, though. I recommend to start with this aspect of the problem.